# Using Foundation in an Electron app

Tags: npm, zurb-foundation, electron, package.json

I'm creating a new Electron app and I'd like to use Foundation for apps and SASS with it. The problem is that Foundation wants me to create a new project where instead I'd rather add Foundation my electron via `npm` or even using `bower` if necessary.

What's the best approach for this?

I've successfully tried adding Foundation-sites as an `npm` dependency to my Electron app's `package.json` but I'm not sure what to do from there. Also is there a Foundation for apps alternative to the Foundation-sites `npm` package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first step is adding Foundation to your project:

```
npm install foundation-sites --save
```

This gives you the Foundation Sass (SCSS) files in `node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/`.

Let's say you have project specific SCSS in `scss/app.scss`, you'd then need to import Foundation SCSS, something like:

```
@import 'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss';

@include foundation-everything
```

Your build process will need to generate CSS from these Sass files - this could be done with various tools such as Gulp, Webpack, Grunt, or simple npm scripts. Then just include the CSS in the HTML files.

The Foundation documentation does cover this using a Grunt example, under [Sass](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sass.html), but it took me a while to find it, since it is not linked to from the installation instructions.

If you prefer to use Foundation for Apps these instructions could easily be adapted for the `foundation-apps` package.

Comment: Quick note: `foundation-apps` [was deprecated](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps) around the same time as this answer was posted. To quote the readme: "we’ve made the decision to streamline our development and move Foundation for Apps into our experimental playground to concentrate on Foundation for Sites".